# plotly plots in jupyter notebooks: Validation fails when saving

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'am new to plotly and I'am having a problem with my plots when generating them inside jupyter notebooks.

Whenever I generate a plot, evrything works fine, but when I try to save the notebook I get an error message telling me that the notebook validation failed because it's not valid under any of the given schemas (example taken straight from the plot.ly webiste).

Here is an example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
iplot([{"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [3, 1, 6]}])
```

I get the following message when I try to save the notebook:
Notebook Validation failed: {u'data': [{u'y': [3, 1, 6], u'x': [1, 2, 3]}], u'layout': {}} is not valid under any of the given schemas:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "y": [
    3, 
    1, 
    6
   ], 
   "x": [
    1, 
    2, 
    3
   ]
  }
 ], 
 "layout": {}
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The ploty team fixed the issue, here is the [ticket](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/692)

Upgrading nbformat, with either

```
pip install --upgrade nbformat
```

or

```
conda update nbformat
```

fixes it.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem but the @gerard's answer didn't help me. I tried then `conda update --all` but this didn't help too.

Later I was given the link: https://gitmemory.com/issue/jupyter/nbformat/161/574959380.
So, I opened ipynb file with text editor,  replaced *"nbformat_minor": 1* with *"nbformat_minor": 4* and saved the file. After reloading the notebook the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As in gerard's answer `pip install --upgrade nbformat` solved the issue, however `conda` (which I tried before `pip`) didn't solve the issue.