# Validation fails when using plotly in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

When I save a jupyter notebook with a plotly graph, I get the following error:

```
[E 13:42:38.458 NotebookApp] Notebook JSON is invalid: {'data': [{'type': 'scatter', 'y': [1, 2, 3]}], 'layout': {}} is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['data']['patternProperties']['^(?!application/json$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\+\\.]+$']:
    {'oneOf': [{'type': 'string'},
               {'items': {'type': 'string'}, 'type': 'array'}]}

On instance['data']['application/vnd.plotly.v1+json']:
    {'data': [{'type': 'scatter', 'y': [1, 2, 3]}], 'layout': {}}
```

My code in the notebook is :

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
data = [go.Scatter(y=[1,2,3])]
py.iplot(data)
```

Following [plotly plots in jupyter notebooks: Validation fails when saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285255/plotly-plots-in-jupyter-notebooks-validation-fails-when-saving#42375401), I updated nbformat but still not working (I checked with `import nbformat` `nbformat__version__` that the update worked)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Copy and pasting any of these examples into a jupyter notebook (and changing the last line to plot offline) reproduces the validation error. https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem. I tried updating nbformat and even *conda update --all* but this didn't help too.

Later I was given a link: https://gitmemory.com/issue/jupyter/nbformat/161/574959380.
So, I opened ipynb file with text editor,  replaced *"nbformat_minor": 1* with *"nbformat_minor": 4* and saved the file. After reloading the notebook the problem was fixed.

Comment: This 'hack' worked too for me, thanks! Do you know what this ``nbformat_minor`` does? Is it related to the used version of nbformat and could also be set 'globaly' by conda or pip installing the correct version?

Comment: @Hellvetia, unfortunately, I don't know. Maybe it switches the save mode to "offline" or something like that. If you find out, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

I got a different error -

```
Notebook validation failed: {'type': 'string'} is not valid under any of the given schemas: { "type": "string" }
```

But replacing "nbformat_minor": 1 with "nbformat_minor": 4 worked for me.