# Notebook Validation Failed | Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

A frustrating and persistent error keeps popping up on my Jupyter Notebook:

The save operation succeeded, but the notebook does not appear to be valid. The validation error was:

```
Notebook validation failed: Additional properties are not allowed ('id' was unexpected):
{
 "metadata": {
  "trusted": true
 },
 "id": "breathing-seventh",
 "cell_type": "code",
 "source": "import pandas as pd\nimport numpy as np\nimport re\nimport datetime\n\nimport json\nimport os\nimport copy\n\nimport seaborn as sns\nimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt",
 "execution_count": 1,
 "outputs": []
}
```

It points to my imports column which contains:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import datetime

import json
import os
import copy

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I'm also using Plotly in the notebook and I'm unsure if the error was caused by Plotly. I looked up the error and used the fixes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285255/plotly-plots-in-jupyter-notebooks-validation-fails-when-saving) but the error still persists.

Please Advise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is due to a fairly recent [change in `nbformat`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/pull/189), which was described in detail [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/62-cell-id/cell-id.html).  Basically, nbformat 4.5 introduced these `id` tags (which you'll probably find in every cell if you look for them), so every notebook stored in an earlier format *should not* have those tags — if an early-format notebook has them, it's considered an error.

So somehow your notebook was partially updated to have `id` tags, but not the nbformat listed in the notebook's metadata.  This has also happened to me, and it's surely a bug.  (I think the update is supposed to happen via `nbformat`, in which [v5.1.1 will automatically convert 4.x up to 4.5](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id1); but I have 5.1.2.  That and *every* other package are as up-to-date as conda will give me, and I've restarted my jupyter server.)

Anyway, the way to solve this problem is to open up your notebook in a text editor (which could be Jupyter Notebook's built-in text editor if you temporarily change the `.ipynb` extension to `.txt`).  Scroll to the very bottom, where the last few lines should look something like this:

```json
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 1
}
```

You should be safe to change that `nbformat_minor` number to 5, save the file, and open the notebook again as usual.  You won't get those notifications again.

Comment: I did this but now I get a `'Unsupported nbformat version 5'` error. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure you set `nbformat_minor` to 5, but left `nbformat` as 4?  Have you updated all your notebook-related packages?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I changed `nbformat` to 5 and that's why it wasn't working. Thank you :)

Comment: What a wonderful answer, thanks for this. Solved the issue in one shot.

Comment: If this minor version upgrade is safe (we implicitly assume here that major version is the same), it could be arguably done automatically by Jupyter metadata validation code... (`nbformat==5.8.0` still does not do it) so why not open a Github Issue?

Comment: @mirekphd I haven't run into this at all recently.  But if you're running into it — and especially if you can provide details — you should absolutely feel free to open an issue.

Comment: Hand-editing the minor format into the notebook file did not solve the problem for me.  The next thing I tried was to open each offending file in Jupyter and save it right away.  This added the expected `id` as needed.  No more warnings from Sphinx when building.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with older notebooks in virtualenvs with older python packages. It usually disappears when I update all my python packages in that virtualenv.

Comment: I've tried updating a few packages that were mentioned in other questions but still hasn't fixed the issue

Comment: I wasn't selective, I just updated all of them so I can't tell you which ones mattered. But I suspect it is the jupyter-related ones.

Comment: Well I've updated the Juptyer ones but I can't seem to figure out why it points elsewhere

Comment: It just points to the first cell that has this 'id' key which happens to be your the cell with your imports.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by running

```
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I pasted the cells from notebook-1 to notebook-2.

The simple solution is if you have your code in a cell that you would intend to reuse, then don't copy the cell but only copy the content in the cell.

In this way, I was able to resolve the error.